# VBA or function to connect 2x CSV files into 1x XLSX

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013

Greets,

I got this scenario with 3x different files;

1) one CSV file has Column A (-first row) with abbreviations that needs to be copied on XLSX file (also in Column A)

+

2) another CSV has many rows and column where is explanation for the first case (abbrevations), and I have to look for explanation inside that big file (so vlookup I used).

=

3) xlsx file is separate that has to combine both CSV into one, where on Column A I will have abbreviations and on Column B explanations of the certain terms.

[image]

I tried with functions and simply defining ranges:

```
Column A1 ='C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\1\[0528-matrix.csv]0528-matrix'!A3

Column B1 =VLOOKUP(A1;'C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\1\[variantendb.csv]variantendb'!$C:$D;2;0)
```

So seems nothing hard or else, but problem is I am having XXX of these CSV files and one main CSV file with explanations (it is stated as "varianten") , that are gonna be updated periodically - all of the files.

Instead to open three files at the same time just to refresh my functions, is it a bit quicker way with a code or other functions?? And I would like to have it in XLSX file.

I tried to record a macro but it didnt work good, I was thinking I can use it for rest of the files but always gives an error.

```
Application.Left = 2318.5
Application.Top = 89.5
Windows("0528-matrix1.xlsx").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='0528-matrix.csv'!R[1]C"
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A1:A500").Select
ActiveWindow.Close
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
Application.Left = 2161
Application.Top = 1
Application.Width = 720
Application.Height = 780
Windows("0528-matrix1.xlsx").Activate
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],variantendb.csv!C3:C4,2,0)"
Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B500")
Range("B1:B500").Select
Application.Left = 1896.25
Application.Top = 32.5
Application.Width = 864
Application.Height = 493.5
Windows("variantendb.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close
Application.Left = 1669
Application.Top = 1
ChDir "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\1"
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using for this?

Comment: @chaosbydesign Office365 , why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Office 365 we can use the [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/get-transform-in-excel-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) feature to create links to your CSV files.  As long as you maintain the same filenames on the CSVs, this will enable Excel to automatically update the data.

We'll complete this data merge in 3 stages:

1. Link the reference CSV (the second file you have listed) to a table
2. Link to the data CSV (the first file) to a table
3. Write an Index/Match function to pull the descriptions.

Stage 1:  Linking the reference file to a table

1. In a new Excel workbook, click on the Data tab, then click on the New Query dropdown in the Get & Transform section.  Mouse over "From File >" and select "From CSV"
2. Navigate to CSV 2 and click Import
3. On the next window that pops up, click "Load"
4. Your lookup data will now load into a table on a new sheet.  Now let's clean up the references here:
5. Click on the Formulas tab, then Click on Name Manager
6. Select your new table (it will be named the same as your file)
7. Change the name to "Reference" and click Ok.
8. Go to your table and change the column names from "Column 1" and "Column 2" to "Abbr" and "Desc"

And that's it for stage 1!  Now that we have the reference table set up and linked, we can move on to loading the data table we want to find the descriptions for.

Stage 2: Linking the data file to a table

1. We're going to link to the data file in the same way we did the reference file.  Go to Data > Get & Transform > New Query > From File > From CSV.  Select your file and click Import, then click Load.
2. On the new table, rename Column 1 to "Code" (I would use Abbr, but Code will help keep the next step looking clear).
3. Add another column to this table.  The simplest way is to just click in B1, type "Desc" (or whatever name of your choosing) and hit Enter.

Stage 3: The Index function that makes the magic

1. On your new data table with the blank description column, click in the first data cell.
2. Type in the function `=INDEX(Reference[Desc],MATCH([@Code],Reference[Abbr],0))` and press Enter.
3. Watch the magic happen as Excel copies our formula to every cell in that table column!

By setting up our CSV files as external connections in this manner, we're able to create a dynamic table that will always update with the CSVs.

By using Index/Match, we're able to get away from the constraints of VLookup (data in left-most field, sorted alphabetically), and move to a system that allows us to look for the value we need from any field in any order.

Breaking it down, Index returns the value of the cell provided in the target row and column of the specified array or table.  Because we specified the target array as a single column of data, we can use `Index([array], [row number])`, or using the code above `Index(Reference[Desc], [row number])`.  What really makes this work is the use of `Match`.  Match returns the row number in an array of a target value, so we use `MATCH([@Code],Reference[Abbr],0)`.  This returns the row number to `Index`, which then pulls the data from the desired cell.

There are some additional steps we can do using the Power Query Editor to ensure the column headers always stay the same, but that's a tutorial for a different day.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow! You have read my mind - PowerQuery came into my head just when I went to the gym and told myself, damn I totally forgot about, went into the Jungle of codes and functions for nothing.

I just super-easily followed your detailed description - works as exactly I imagined how it should. YOu at least understood my messy question.

Power Query is miracle, I am using it but I didnt consider it for this...Index/match never let down...impressive. 

High five! Thank you!

Comment: I got small issue when trying to refresh populated data into most of the CSV files. It shows Abbr but without Desc, I checked in a case of misspelling but no, it is just empty space..would be an error or else in a case of missing. So I have to click manually to expand whole formula... any suggest?

Comment: Is that anything to do because at Work I am using office 2016? That time home I did with office365... just to ask...

Comment: Sorry for this spamming! Strange, works for OFFICE 365 without single mistake as it was...but at work not (Excel 2016).  I mean it works partially, here is automatically populated.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response - in order to keep the custom column names, you have to open it in the Power Query Editor and add the rename steps for each column.  Right now it's defaulting to Column 1 / Column 2.

Comment: They are already the same...I used this workbook that I made home on office 365. So I didnt make any changes and it didnt make any changes...only refresh isnt as expected. It isnt populating properly...

Comment: Refreshing pivot and formulas inside, no matter which version of Excel (I tried od 2013, 2016 and O365):

Select cell in table –> table tools –> Properties –> Check box “Preserve column soft/filter/layout and click OK”

However! this needs to be done before the Excel table column is added (and calculated) to the table from the Query.

Comment: Hi, I remembered you helped me greatly with this task using PQ, and now I got some maybe similar issue which I cant find out. I posted already here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237971/excel-finding-the-right-match-from-matrix-scheme

..but no response. Seems like an easy job maybe but no success for me. Maybe you got some tip or else?

Sorry that I am writing in this way, but it came all of a sudden that I might ask some user for assistance. 

Thx in advance!