# Excel: Finding the right match from matrix "scheme"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, matching, excel-2013, excel-2016

I am trying to "match" values or patterns from one sheet to another. I got like "matrix scheme" (the first pic) where I am looking for a certain pattern which is labeled as " _ " and "1". If there is a match ("1"), I should color it in red, or green when no match (" _ "). But that part is easy. 
As you can see there are 4 "cases" for now, and that is exactly what I want to have on another sheet (the second pic) as match. But I am getting only one match (from Column S ("XC0")) and empty spaces (" _ ") for others even if there is a match.

[image]

Here is my match table (on picture beneath) where I used this function:

```
=VLOOKUP($A10;_0528_matrix[#All];MATCH(A$10;_0528_matrix[#Headers];0);0)
```

**Index/Match** also gave me the same results. These **NA errors** are fine for now, that's what I am gonna remove later.

[image]

Tried with this and still nothing...

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("_0528_matrix[" & A2 & "]"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need a count, not just a match. In this case, try putting this in the cell **`A3`**:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("_0528_matrix[" & A2 & "]");"1")
```

Another version:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Matrix;0;MATCH(A10;Matrix[#Headers];0));"1")
```

Comment: Damn! This looks 90% great :D I tested..but the only thing  I am receiving "1" on first position where it shouldnt be if you look at the matrix... 200PD has "_" so it should give 0 right?  Other matches are great, correct!!

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is fine actually. Your function is matching everything what is good, and I just need to adjust "1s and 0s" to change the color depending on combination of them. Perfect man! You helped my enormously !!!

Comment: It is okay to use Indirect for my example, small scaled...but not for long term solution or when data got bigger or updated. But I am fine for now!! Appreciated your help ! Greets

Comment: Later just ask another question here, someone will definitely help :)

Comment: Hey man! sorry, I found solution number 2 also:

=COUNTIF(INDEX(Matrix;0;MATCH(A10;Matrix[#Headers];0));"1")

It works as yours =)))